# How to render Razor in cshtml page with Servicestack without content page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, servicestack

I have markdown in string property of my model and would like to render it onto page. If I have html in that same string property I would simply do:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.BodyHtml)
```

Is there a same thing if string contains Markdown rather than Html? I.e. something like:

```
@Html.MarkdownToHtml(Model.BodyMarkdown)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `@Html.RenderMarkdownToHtml()` API for this has just been added in **v4.0.34+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet), which will let you render markdown with:

```
@Html.RenderMarkdownToHtml(Model.BodyMarkdown)
```

In earlier versions of ServiceStack you would call the Markdown implementation itself to render HTML and use the `AsRaw()` extension method so the returned HTML isn't automatically encoded, e.g:

```
@(new MarkdownSharp.Markdown().Transform(Model.BodyMarkdown).AsRaw())
```