# Markdown for single value inside Razor

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

Is there any quick way to render a value as Markdown within a ServiceStack Razor page?

E.g. @MyText.ToMarkdown() or something?

Comment: I just found this question, which seems to be almost the same, but with a very different title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199738/how-to-render-razor-in-cshtml-page-with-servicestack-without-content-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
@Html.RenderMarkdownToHtml("## Heading2")
```

Or you could transform the markdown to HTML manually and embed the raw HTML with:

```
@(new MarkdownSharp.Markdown().Transform("## Heading2").AsRaw())
```